# Are randomness and probability really logically dependent notions?

Tags: probability, references, randomness

## Background

[Some have lamented that it is difficult to distinguish randomness from probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143469/is-there-any-difference-between-random-and-probabilistic), but I seem to be having a contrary difficulty: are they even logically dependent notions?

### Probability

While introductions to Statistics abound that will take for granted a relationship between probability and the notion of randomness, I am finding this relationship to be more optional as I [read](https://www.amazon.ca/Measure-Theory-Probability-Krishna-Athreya/dp/038732903X) into the foundations of probability theory. It seems that probability theory doesn't require a notion of randomness to satisfy the axioms of Measure Theory and Kolmogorov. Some disciplines, such as [Ergodic Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory), even compute expectations (which involve probability measures) on purely deterministic systems.

### Randomness

Randomness itself doesn't appear to be a precise notion. Most often I see definitions similar to "the property of being unpredictable". One can notice that some systems can be extrinsically random in the sense that there are models that reduce previously-unpredictable phenomena into a [pseudorandom process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness). According to [Chaos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory), this can simply be a matter of knowing the governing equations and the relevant initial conditions with enough precision. Perhaps aspects of Quantum Mechanics are instrinsically random, but [even that is not a given](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2020.00139/full) in my view.

The closest I have found to a formal notion of randomness is information entropy, which itself goes back to being a consequence of probability theory.

All it seems to take is complexity resulting from not knowing the state-transition rules or the state of a system and we seem to get randomness.

### Summary

In summary, (1) probability theory doesn't seem to need a notion of randomness and (2) it is not clear whether randomness is anything more than limited predictability when relevant details are missing. At a glance these notions seem inseparable, but after a long gaze they seem to be at-most in a casual relationship.

## Question

Who can I read that really cuts into the meat of this problem?

Comment: There is also so-called "algorithmic randomness", "Martin-Löf randomness", etc.

Comment: @PeterO. Is there a difference between algorithmic randomness and [algorithmic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)? Thank you for mentioning [Martin-Löf randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence). I will read into it.

Comment: Probability theory is about randomness. Saying the the former doesn’t need the latter is like saying biology doesn’t need living organisms

Comment: @Aksakal That is a powerful [simile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile). The difficulty expressed above is not about intuition or a desired use case of probability theory. The axioms of probability theory as developed by Kolmogorov simply don't require the notion.

Comment: I am afraid kolmogorov would disagree. He was very well grounded in experiment. In fact in the preface to The book he says that the axioms are based on experiment in a broad sense: the theory needs to explain reality. The axioms need to correspond to what we know about the world. It’s very similar to geometry where axioms are extracted from what we learned about space around us. Yes, once the axioms are written one can forget about reality and just work with theory. However it is the connection with reality that brings most interesting developments in the theory again and again

Comment: @Aksakal Kolmogorov's axioms of probability theory are not the same as the whole of what Kolmogorov thought about probability theory, and you are appealing to his views beyond the axioms themselves. My concern doesn't invoke any of his views beyond the axioms, nor does his informal treatment seem to adequately unpack my concerns. I'm not advocating that we disregard reality (i.e. observation), or theory for that matter. I simply want to have the clearest understanding of the relations between these concepts as I can practically obtain. Hence a reference request to further that understanding.

Comment: The clearest relation is that axioms are constructed in such a way that whatever comes out of them should match all the random processes in physical world. If there's any kind of inconsistency, then the set of axioms will need to be modified. It's very simple. I'm afraid you're looking for something that's not there at this point.

Comment: @Aksakal Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You'd find the same studying Geometry or Mechanics: any bit of Maths only refers to sets in the end, & bridge principles are needed to connect it with the notions to which we want to apply it. Gillies (2000), *Philosophical Theories of Probability* is a good introduction; & IIRC makes the point that the Kolmogorov axioms could just as well be applied to the lengths of a collection of sticks as to anything having to do with random processes (or the credibility of propositions).

Comment: The rewrite of your question makes it sound like “does a custom fit jacket really need a man to wear it?” - you expect us to say that it can simply be used in other ways. The problem with this approach is that if you keep working on it without expectation that a man will wear it, after a few adjustments it will stop being a jacket or even looking like one

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Gillies (2000) *Philosophical Theories of Probability* sounds interesting. I will try to find it.

Comment: @Aksakal Yes, that seems to be a metaphorical restatement of the opinion you expressed above.

Comment: Apparently David Deutsch would rather get rid of probability altogether. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfzSE4Hoxbc

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, this type of question, although common, does not seem to have a lot of answers to be found. So let us try to answer it here.

First of all, to define randomness we need to define a context. That first step may not seem obvious so we belabor that point a bit here. Consider, please, that all information is context dependent, and being as we wish to define something that does not contain a certain type of information, we need to specify a context before we can impose an absence of information.

Consider, for example, that we might wish to consider a quasi-infinite sequence of binary numbers; 1's and 0's. That does several things. First of all, that context, although arguably arbitrary, is also quite restricted in the sense that we only allow 1's and 0's, and disallow all other possible characters.

Having imposed that context, we can proceed to define randomness as the absence of any structure to the sequence of 1's and 0's, so it is actually a very simple definition, and that definition lends itself to testing, in fact, such testing has no bounds.

So then probability, what is that? As the OP stated, randomness and probability are strange bedfellows, but they are not entirely unrelated in the sense that to test a sequence of 1's and 0's for a lack of structure, we would have to introduce a new concept, that of the likelihood of finding structure, and if there is truly is none but we intuit a structure, then we have made a mistake. So what then is probability? One thing that probability is that it relates to an estimate of structure within an information context.

Returning to our problem, one probability that corresponds to a lack of structure is a 50% probability of 1's and 0's, but we need a lot more than that, for example, the sequence $10101010101010101010101010\dots$ has an equal probability of 1's and 0's but it is structured, i.e., ever other number is a 0. So in sum, randomness is a pertinent lack structure within a context, which context, although it may seem to be contradictory for it to be so, can be highly structured.